# PHP MYSQL UPDATE WHERE multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I was wondering if you can do an Update with multiple conditions like so:

```
UPDATE participantes SET confirmado = 1 WHERE id = 19 AND id = 20 AND id = 21;
```

participantes -> Table

confirmado -> field of the table participantes.

Comment: In that case, no - you'd need `id` to be three different values. You can try `WHERE id IN (19,20,21)` to update multiple rows; or `WHERE cond1=19 AND cond2=20` for checking different fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL's AND clause will only work when ALL of the criteria are met. What you're looking for is OR. In the format that you provided:

```
UPDATE participantes SET confirmado = 1 WHERE id = 19 OR id = 20 OR id = 21;
```

Although, the above-noted IN (19, 20, 21) would be better for this specific use case.

Your original query was trying to look for a single row where id was simultaneously 19, 20, and 21, which would never happen.

Answer (score 9):

To accomplish what you're describing, I would, instead, use the `IN` clause:

```
UPDATE participantes SET confirmado = 1 WHERE id IN(19, 20, 21);
```

Comment: Almost wrote this exactly, kudos

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
UPDATE participantes SET confirmado = 1 WHERE id >= 19 AND id != 50 AND id != 51;
```

Comment: I tried this (AND) multiple times and different query but it doesn't seem to work